# Latitude and Longitude

Tags: sql-server, geo

I have table 1 that has North, South, East and West coordinates for a specific region.

On each record in table 2, I have Latitude and Longitude coordinates.  How do I write a query to see if these coordinates are in the designated range specified in table 1

Table 1:

```
MapNorthLat MapSouthLat MapEastLong MapWestLong
36.912220   33.738137   -76.189200  -82.380500
```

Table 2

```
_Geo_Lat    _Geo_Lon
34.23184    -77.929218
```

Not having any luck with the logic of this code

Comment: Much depends on how the data in table 1 is structured. Please provide example data.

Comment: Table 1: 
MapNorthLat MapSouthLat MapEastLong MapWestLong
36.912220 33.738137 -76.189200 -82.380500

Table 2
_Geo_Lat _Geo_Lon
34.23184 -77.929218

Comment: What are you table definitions i.e. what datatypes are you using to store your data.

Comment: `select *
from table1 as a
join table2 as b on 
geography::STPolyFromText(concat('POLYGON((',
  a.MapWestLong, ' ', a.MapNorthLat, ',', 
  a.MapWestLong, ' ', a.MapSouthLat, ',', 
  a.MapEastLong, ' ', a.MapSouthLat, ',',
  a.MapEastLong, ' ', a.MapNorthLat, ',',
  a.MapWestLong, ' ', a.MapNorthLat, '))'), 4326).STIntersects(geography::Point(b._Geo_Lat, b._Geo_Lon, 4326)) = 1`